# Simplest of Image Rotators - Failing with SetInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

Failing with the simplest of image rotators, how can i get this to just cycle through the array?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var source = ["images/designers1.jpg","images/designers2.jpg","images/designers3.jpg"];
     i=0;
     setInterval(function(){
         $('.dimg').attr('src',source[i++])
     }, 2000);
 });
```

Comment: Please tell us what fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var source = ["http://dummyimage.com/300x200/FFF/F00&text=GoodBye","http://dummyimage.com/300x200/000/fff&text=Hello"];
     var i=0;
     setInterval(function() {
         $('.dimg').attr('src', source[i++ % source.length])
     }, 2000);
 });
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QXyjS/

Changes:

1. Each image is only in the array once.
2. The index into the array is modulo the length of the array so it will never exceed the length of the array
3. `var` is added in front of the `i` variable so it is not global.

Comment: awesome jfriend00 - what does % source.length mean?

Comment: `i % source.length` divides `i` by `source.length` and the value of that expression is the remainder of the division operation.  So, if `i` was `3`, it would be the remainder of 3/2 which is 1.  This is a common trick to stay within the array and get wrapping/repeating values.  In this example, it will go `0`, `1`, `0`, `1`, etc...  See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) for the `%` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var source = ["images/designers1.jpg","images/designers2.jpg","images/designers1.jpg"];
     var idx = 0;

     function animate(idx) {
         idx++;
         if (idx >= source.length)
             idx = 0;
         $(".dimg").attr("src", source[idx]);
         setTimeout(function() {
             animate(idx);
         }, 2000);
     }
     animate(idx);
 });
```

[edit] `setInterval` is bad! Use recursive `setTimeout` calls to avoid some nasty pitfalls. And a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/QXyjS/3/) can be found as well.

Comment: hmmmmmm @nietonfir i was considering a loop, but then i'd just remove the set interval, because that is supposed to run on a loop of its own, no?

Comment: Why are you setting multiple `setInterval()` calls.  Doesn't seem like what anyone wants.

Comment: @rootsup With `setInterval` the function is called asynchronously.  The timer does not wait until the function completes before starting over.  So, if any call to the function takes longer than the timer interval you'll get out-of-order execution at a minimum, and potentially memory leaks/performance issues also (depending on what's going on in the function).